# Problems launching Firefox: "Couldn't load XPCOM"

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I can't open my Firefox. I don't remember well how this problem came on, but apparently I've never made any changes to my computer or Firefox itself since the last time I could launch it successfully. I'm using Windows 7 Pro 64 Bits. Now, whenever I open Firefox, there is always an error message saying, "Couldn't load XPCOM". I haven't reinstalled Firefox since I don't wanna lose my important bookmarks. I hope you can help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This message indicates failure to load `xpcom.dll`. Check the installation directory (most probably `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\`) if it is there.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after firefox notified me to upgrade and I clicked to do so.  I used chrome browser to download the newest version of firefox (22) and it works OK now (all my settings retained).  xpcom.dll is not now in the mozilla firefox directory.  Maybe it is not used in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Start Firefox in [Safe Mode](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) to check if one of the extensions (Firefox/Tools > Add-ons > Extensions) or if hardware acceleration is causing the problem (switch to the DEFAULT theme: Firefox/Tools > Add-ons > Appearance).

Do not click the Reset button on the Safe mode start window or otherwise make changes.
[Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/Safe+Mode)
[Mozilla Theme Support](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/Troubleshooting+extensions+and+themes)

Answer (score 0):

You can **re-install Firefox** by just making a **backup of your settings** first. Do it via cloud sync (go to settings and click on sync) or backup the folder in your user directory.

> C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox

Otherwise here is a [thread on mozilla](http://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/943596).